# (Discord.py) How Do I Alter Pre-Existing JSON to add a new Parameter?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add a new item to a shop in my discord, and I have it set to where people have to open an account before they can participate in the economy. Here is what I currently have in way of code to add this new item:

```
    @commands.hybrid_command(name = "update_shop", description = "An administrative command used to update everyone's inventories when the shop is updated!")
    @commands.has_role("*")
    async def update_shop(self, ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
      with open("cogs/inventory.json", "r") as f:
        inventory = json.load(f)
      if f"{user.id}" in inventory:
        inventory[user.id]["law_tuition"] = 0
        with open("cogs/inventory.json", "w") as f:
          json.dump(inventory, f)
        await ctx.send("Done!")
```

I don't get any errors, but the JSON also doesn't update. I don't even get the "Done!" message!

Edit: Below is a sample of JSON:

```
{"[USER ID, REDACTED FOR PRIVACY": {"small_apartment": 0, "news_station": 0, "empty_storefront": 0, "business_down_payment": 0}...}
```

Comment: If you don't get your `"Done!"` message, then maybe `f"{user.id}" in inventory` is `False`? Please update your question with a relevant sample from `"cogs/inventory.json"`.

Comment: Done, sorry. Meant to add a sample.

Comment: Ok, but can you give us some fake user ids? Will `f"{user.id}"` be the same as `"[USER ID, REDACTED FOR PRIVACY"`?

Comment: Yes, it would, in theory. My discord user ID, for example, is 392528216662736898. That would be user.id in this instance.

Comment: Ok, so that should work: The `id` is stored as a string in the `json` file (`{"392528216662736898": {"small_apartment": 0, ...`) and the expression: `f"{user.id}"` produces a string, so the boolean expression should work. Are those assumptions correct?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help, but I just figured it out myself. I'm about to post my answer. Thanks so much though!

Answer (score 0):

your solution is very inefficient. Like someone in the comments pointed out, you are writing to the file in each iteration.

To optimize the code and write to the file only once, you can move the file writing outside of the loop.  This way, the file is opened and written to only once after all updates have been made to the inventory dictionary, which is more efficient.

Do this instead:

```
with open("cogs/inventory.json", "r") as f:
            inventory = json.load(f)

        # Update the law_tuition for each user
        for user_id, user_data in inventory.items():
            if user_id in inventory:
                inventory[user_id]["law_tuition"] = 0

        # Write the updated inventory back to the file
        with open("cogs/inventory.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(inventory, f)

        # Send a message indicating that the update is done
        await ctx.send("Done!")
```

Answer (score -1):

After a little tinkering, I figured it out myself!

```
    @commands.hybrid_command(name = "update_shop", description = "An administrative command used to update everyone's inventories when the shop is updated!")
    @commands.has_role("*")
    async def update_shop(self, ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
      with open("cogs/inventory.json", "r") as f:
        inventory = json.load(f)
      for user_id, user_data in inventory.items():
        if user_id in inventory:
          inventory[user_id]["law_tuition"] = 0
          with open("cogs/inventory.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(inventory, f)
          await ctx.send("Done!")
```

worked.

Comment: Your code makes no sense now. Since you are iterating over *all* items, every single `user_id` **is** in `inventory`. This means you are setting every user to have: `"law_tuition": 0` (**And** you are writing once to the file for every user).